# SQL Server: remove duplicate references to only use uniques

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem figuring out how to do the following in SQL Server.

Let's say we have 2 tables:

- 1 for emails and their attachments (called `BigTable`)
- 1 for a reference between them (called `BigTableReference`)

Over time, there will be multiple unique attachments (maybe 2-4), but we save 2 new ones every time we send an email resulting in a lot of duplicates.

What I would like to do is:

- Find the unique attachments and update the link in the reference table to link to the unique attachments.
- Then delete all duplicate attachments.

The relationship between the tables are as follows:

- An attachment has an `Id` which is found in the `Reference` table
- The `Reference` table then has a `RefId` which corrospond to email's Id in the first table

Right now we have the following:

(To Email 001 is two attachments - Attachment 001 and Attachment 002)

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| BigTable  |          BigTableReference          |    BigTable     |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Email 001 | Email 001 -> Attachment 001 + 002   | Attachment 001  |
| Email 002 | Email 002 -> Attachment 003 + 004   | Attachment 002  |
| Email 003 | Email 003 -> Attachment 005 + 006   | Attachment 003  |
| ...       | ...                                 |                 |
| Email 999 | Email 999 -> Attachment 1997 + 1998 | Attachment 1998 |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+

         Id -> RefId                          Id -> Id
```

After the SQL is run I would like it to look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| BigTable  |         BigTableReference         |    BigTable    |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| Email 001 | Email 001 -> Attachment 001 + 002 | Attachment 001 |
| Email 002 | Email 002 -> Attachment 001 + 002 | Attachment 002 |
| Email 003 | Email 003 -> Attachment 001 + 002 |                |
| ...       | ...                               |                |
| Email 999 | Email 999 -> Attachment 001 + 002 |                |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
```

Anyone with more knowledge than me who can help me in the right direction?

Comment: how do you identify duplicate attachments?

Comment: They are saved as binaries. So they would have the same content in the "Binary01" field.

Comment: I think it'll help if you show us real table structure with real data instead of referring to them as big table, bigger table, etc

Comment: just to be clear, you only have 2-4 unique attachments, which fill BigTable with duplicates? if the size difference is so big, creating new table or truncating will be much faster then delete

Comment: Hmm, they are actually called BigTable and BigTableReference. Don't know how I can visualize this better.

Comment: @Hamawi : I am not allowed to create new tables. BigTable contains alot of things and one of those is email attachments.

Comment: just to be sure. how big are those tables?

Comment: BigTable = 96920 rows and BigTableReference = 225784 rows

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo. Adjust it according to real tables and columns. Updated BigTableReference refers to first occurences of 'Test1' and 'Test2' only.

```
-- demo setup
create table BigTable(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    Binary01 varbinary(max)
)
insert  into BigTable (Binary01)
        values
         (cast('Test1' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test1' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test2' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test2' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test1' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test1' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test1' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test2' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test2' as varbinary(max)))
        ,(cast('Test2' as varbinary(max)))
;

create table BigTableReference(
        ID int identity(1,1),
        attID int
);

insert into BigTableReference(attId)
select top 100 
       (row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1)
         % (select max(id) from Bigtable) + 1
from sys.all_objects;

select * from BigTableReference;

-- query 
update btr
set attID = newId
from BigTableReference btr
join (
  select id, min(id) over(partition by Binary01) newid
  from BigTable
) converter on converter.id = btr.attId  ;
```